# Android DrawArc SweepGradient over 360°

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make a wheel of colours which allows the user to select between Solid color or Gradients.
The user can also move those colours around the wheel.

The problem is with the gradient. When the angle is over 360° the colour displayed is going back to the first colour instead of continue the gradient.

I'm using a custom view and the code I will paste is called from the onDraw method.

```
int start = Color.rgb((int)previous.startRed, (int)previous.startGreen, (int)previous.startBlue);
int end = Color.rgb((int)previous.endRed, (int)previous.endGreen, (int)previous.endBlue);
int[] colors = {start, end, end};
float from = from_angle / 360.0f;
float to = (from_angle + to_angle) / 360.0f;
float[] positions = {from,to, to};
Log.v("Print", "print positions " + positions[0] + " " + positions[1]);
Shader gradient = new SweepGradient (oval.centerX(), oval.centerY(),colors, positions);
paint.setShader(gradient);
canvas.drawArc(oval, from_angle, to_angle + 1, false, paint);
```

Here is a picture to show the problem I face.[image]

Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: simply don't use angle > 360

Comment: But I don't want to block my wheel. And there's no problem with the draw arc when I'm over 360, I wonder if theres a solution on the creation of the SweepGradient to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: Shader.setLocalMatrix ?

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. I used it and it works.
I'm not going over 360 anymore, I'm starting from 0 to the expected angle, and then I rotate my angle.